# Android WebView: Wait for display-update until page rendering is complete

Tags: android, webview, display

I'm building a simple WebApp for an e-Ink device. Since these devices are not great at refreshes I'd like to reduce strain of the display by only presenting the completely loaded page and avoid the "element wiggling to its final place" a normal browser does while loading a page.

The only somewhat crude solution I've come up with so far is to hide the WebView in *shouldOverrideUrlLoading()* and display it back in *onPageFinished()*. But I'm hoping that there is a more elegant solution - preferably one that keeps the old page on display until loading of the new page is complete and than switches over in one go.

One final issue: The device I'm working with still runs with Kitkat so modern approaches are out of the question.